# ASP.NET - Keep DropDownList selection on repeater DataBound

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu, postback, repeater

I have two `DropDownLists` per item on a `Repeater`.

I am binding both lists to two different lists on the repeater `DataBound`.

Both lists have an `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event handler which does some calculations based on the selections in both `DropDownLists`. Both lists also have `AutoPostBack="True"`.

I need the calculation to be updated immediately. So I added another data binding for the repeater - on the lists' event handler.

This is the problem however - the repeater "resets" the selections to -1 and eventually the first items in both `DropDownLists` are displayed.

How can I make sure the selections remain after the data binding?

Here is the repeater structure:

```
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptCart">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="size"><div><asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="_selectSize" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="selectChange" EnableViewState="true" TabIndex="<%#Container.ItemIndex%>"></asp:DropDownList></div></td>
                        <td class="material"><div><asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="_selectMaterial" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="selectChange" EnableViewState="true" TabIndex="<%#Container.ItemIndex%>"></asp:DropDownList></div></td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

And the repeater `DataBound`:

```
Protected Sub rptCart_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptCart.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
        Dim sizeSelect As DropDownList = CType(e.Item.FindControl("_selectSize"), DropDownList)
        Dim materialSelect As DropDownList = CType(e.Item.FindControl("_selectMaterial"), DropDownList)

        sizeSelect.DataSource = sizeList
        sizeSelect.DataBind()
        materialSelect.DataSource = materialList
        materialSelect.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

And finally the `DropDownLists` event handler:

```
Protected Sub selectChange(ByVal sender As DropDownList, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim listing As New PriceListing
    Dim ddl As DropDownList
    Dim selectedIndex As Integer

    If sender.ID = "_selectSize" Then
        For Each rptrItem As RepeaterItem In rptCart.Items
            ddl = CType(rptrItem.FindControl("_selectMaterial"), DropDownList)
            If ddl.TabIndex = sender.TabIndex Then Exit For
        Next

        For Each listing In artDecoPricing
            If listing.Size = sender.SelectedValue Then Exit For
        Next

        selectedIndex = ddl.SelectedIndex
    ElseIf sender.ID = "_selectMaterial" Then
        For Each rptrItem As RepeaterItem In rptCart.Items
            ddl = CType(rptrItem.FindControl("_selectSize"), DropDownList)
            If ddl.TabIndex = sender.TabIndex Then Exit For
        Next

        For Each listing In artDecoPricing
            If listing.Size = ddl.SelectedValue Then Exit For
        Next

        selectedIndex = sender.SelectedIndex
    End If

    Select Case selectedIndex
        Case 0
            Cart.Order.Items(sender.TabIndex).PriceUnit = listing.Canvas
        Case 1
            Cart.Order.Items(sender.TabIndex).PriceUnit = listing.Acrylic
        Case 2
            Cart.Order.Items(sender.TabIndex).PriceUnit = listing.Framed
        Case 3
            Cart.Order.Items(sender.TabIndex).PriceUnit = listing.Framed
    End Select

    Cart.SaveOrder()

    rptCart.DataSource = Cart.Order.Items
    rptCart.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could store the old selection:

```
Dim sizeSelect As DropDownList = CType(e.Item.FindControl("_selectSize"), DropDownList)
Dim materialSelect As DropDownList = CType(e.Item.FindControl("_selectMaterial"), DropDownList)
Dim sizeSelectedIndex = sizeSelect.SelectedIndex
Dim materialSelectedIndex = materialSelect.SelectedIndex
' do the databinding ... '
sizeSelect.SelectedIndex = If(sizeSelectedIndex < sizeSelect.Items.Count -1, sizeSelectedIndex, -1)
materialSelect.SelectedIndex = If(materialSelectedIndex < materialSelect.Items.Count -1, materialSelectedIndex, -1)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. Now I am having another problem though. I have an additional button control on each item to update the item quantity. It works fine - until I change the selection on one of the dropdowns. What happens is even when I press the linkbutton, it fires first the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event handler and only then the button.click handler! (and it's braking the function). What do you think?

Comment: @user1049693: Ask another question from it since it's difficult to understand what happens from a comment.

Comment: I am having a bit of a problem with your solution :) Your solution causes all items in the repeater to have their DropDownLists values identical to the one that has been changed. I need to be able to do 2 more things: the first one is limit the change to only the drop down that was selected (and not to the rest) AND save the values of all drop downs on all items, to prevent them from being reset in the DataBound. Thank you!

Comment: @pilau: Why only to the previously selected? The ones that were not selected would be deselected afterwards because their SelectedIndex was `-1`. I don't understand your second requirement at all. What does _save_ mean and why do you need that?

Comment: Thank you fro staying in touch. What I mean is: first of all, all DDLs get reset during the repeater DataBound. If I have more than 1 item in the repeater, and I want to keep the values after every PostBack (remember that I need to make some calculations based on the DDLs selected values) - your solution does not apply. Isn't there a more "dynamic" way to accomplish this? Rather then creating a global collection of DDL va;lues for example...
Thanks.

Comment: @pilau: I'm not sure if i took your point. Why does my approach not work for you? It stores the selected index(you can change easily to SelectedValue) in ItemDataBound for **every** RepeaterItem(not only one). What are you missing and where?

Comment: I implemented your solution in a different manner, because when I get to the databound the values in the DDLs are already lost (because the databound occurs after a postback). I imeplemented your solution in a different manner: on the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` handler I stored the indexes for both DDLs of the item the handled DDL originated from in global vars, and fetched the values from them in the DataBound. But that's wrong, since the repeater may contain more than 1 item, and thus more than 1 set of DDLs. I can build a collection of DDL values and use that, but that seems overkill...